# Service php-fpm does not support chkconfig

Tags: php, http, nginx, fastcgi

Everything is working fine.

Just that when i 
chkconfig –add php-fpm

It throws me an error
Service php-fpm does not support chkconfig

php-5.2.13
php-5.2.13-fpm-0.5.13.diff.gz

Below is the configuration i use
./configure --enable-fastcgi --enable-fpm --build=x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu --program-prefix= --prefix=/usr --exec-prefix=/usr --bindir=/usr/bin --sbindir=/usr/sbin --sysconfdir=/etc --datadir=/usr/share --includedir=/usr/include --libdir=/usr/lib64 --libexecdir=/usr/libexec --localstatedir=/var --sharedstatedir=/usr/com --mandir=/usr/share/man --infodir=/usr/share/info --cache-file=../config.cache --with-libdir=lib64 --with-config-file-path=/etc --with-config-file-scan-dir=/etc/php.d --disable-debug --with-pic --disable-rpath --with-pear --with-bz2 --with-curl --with-exec-dir=/usr/bin --with-freetype-dir=/usr --with-png-dir=/usr --enable-gd-native-ttf --without-gdbm --with-gettext --with-gmp --with-iconv --with-jpeg-dir=/usr --with-openssl --with-png --with-expat-dir=/usr --with-pcre-regex=/usr --with-zlib --with-layout=GNU --enable-exif --enable-ftp --enable-magic-quotes --enable-sockets --enable-sysvsem --enable-sysvshm --enable-sysvmsg --enable-track-vars --enable-trans-sid --enable-yp --enable-wddx --with-kerberos --enable-ucd-snmp-hack --with-unixODBC=shared,/usr --enable-memory-limit --enable-shmop --enable-calendar --enable-dbx --enable-dio --with-mime-magic=/usr/share/file/magic.mime --without-sqlite --with-libxml-dir=/usr --with-xml --with-system-tzdata --without-mysql --without-gd --without-odbc --disable-dom --disable-dba --without-unixODBC --disable-pdo --disable-xmlreader --disable-xmlwriter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a php-fpm script in /etc/init.d? That's what chkconfig works off of. It looks for a comment in the script:

```
 # chkconfig: 345 26 74
```

to figure out which runlevels should be configured. If there's no php-fpm init script, or the script doesn't contain that chkconfig comment, then chkconfig has nothing to work off of.

Answer (score 1):

In PHP 5.3.x there is already a file `php-5.3.3/sapi/fpm/init.d.php-fpm` in the source distro that just must be moved to `/etc/rc.d/init.d` folder. Make it executable by chmod +x and you are done and can chkconfig it now.

Answer (score 0):

1. `vi /etc/init.d/php-fpm`

   add these lines on top (modify paths where required):

   ```
   # chkconfig: - 85 15
   # processname: php-cgi
   # config:      /usr/local/php-fpm/etc/php-fpm.conf
   # config:      /etc/sysconfig/php-fpm
   # pidfile:     /usr/local/php-fpm/logs/php-fpm.pid
   ```
2. `vi /etc/sysconfig/php-fpm`

   paste:

   ```
   PHP-FPM_CONF_FILE=/usr/local/php-fpm/etc/php-fpm.conf
   ```

Answer (score 0):

The script must have 2 lines:

```
# chkconfig: <levels> <start> <stop>
```

for example:

```
# chkconfig: 345 99 01

345 - levels to configure
99 - startup order
01 - stop order
After you add the above headers you can run chkconfig --add <service>.
```